# PHP upgrade problems with FastCGI Apache 2.2 Centos 6

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

I am running CentOS release 6.4 (Final). I removed php 5.2.17 via yum and installed php 5.3.3. via yum as well. Since then Apache can't write to files. I've got error:

> failed to open stream: Permission denied

phpinfo() says:

> Server API    CGI/FastCGI

Details:

PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Dec 11 2013 03:29:57)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug 13 2013 17:29:28

Any ideas?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

check that the user that is running your apache has the necessary access rights to read the directory and file

Comment: In case anybody faces same problem - I fixed it by adding SuexecUserGroup ftpuser ftpusergroup to the virtual host configuraion and CHOWNing /var/www/cgi-bin to that ftpuser ftpusergroup.